# DbContext Editable Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, grid, dbcontext

I'm new of DbContext, before of that I used to work with ObjectContext.
Now I'm developing a c# program that works with SQLCompact 4 and EF 4.5.

The problem that I can not resolve is really trivial, or at least it seems like this!

I want load a record set in a grid but when I try to do that, I receive this error:

> {"Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery)
>   is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by
>   calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind
>   to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList()."}

I found a solution that not satisfy my aims.

```
bsData.DataSource = moProject.ctx.SoilResistivity.Local.ToBindingList();
```

I need something like this:

```
bsData.DataSource = moProject.ctx.SoilResistivity.Where(i => i.IDProject == moProject.IDProject);
```

but the data must be modifiable! so ToList() doesn't seems to resolve the problem! when data are showed I can modify these, but are not saved on db with a `ctx.SaveChanges()`.

could you please help me?

thank you very much

Gianluca

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx

Comment: What I can not make is to have a "filtered" selection of my record and the possibility to modify these.

Comment: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. This was the solution: moProject.ctx.SoilResistivity.Where(i => i.IDProject == moProject.IDProject).Load();
                bsData.DataSource = moProject.ctx.SoilResistivity.Local; <br> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65e5ed34-751e-4bd9-90a0-ae83ac81ba6c/ef-41-problem-binding-gridview?forum=adodotnetentityframework